# "hand off", "hand over" and "take over"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In the context of customer support, when a team owns a ticket and it finds out the correct owner should be another team, they "hand the ticket off" and the new team "takes it ower". Why handoff and not "handover and "takeover"?

Comment: A "handover" usually means the person who was doing the task will bring the person who is taking over up to speed. Whereas I think "hand off" implies just change of owner without a handover.

Comment: We don't use "take off" because that means something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

It's informative to see that you too are UK-based and quite probably a Brit. I've heard 'hand off' in its sporting usage, but didn't realise that the transitive multi-word verb (known by many as a transitive 'phrasal verb') *hand off* is used in the States where *hand over* is the usual term in the UK.

The [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hand-sth-off) explains [minor adjustments]:

> **hand off** [transitive phrasal verb based on *hand*]
>
> [US] (UK hand over)
>
> - to pass or give something to someone:
>
> *"Look over there!" he said, handing off his binoculars to the woman standing next to him.*
>
> - in American football, to pass the ball directly into the hands of another player:
>
> *He was happy to hand off the ball more at the start of this season.*
>
> ..........................
>
> [US] (UK hand over) [transitive phrasal verb]
>
> - to give another person control of something, or responsibility for dealing with him, her, or it:
>
> *The work could be handed off to another firm.*
>
> *Sayles wrote the original draft, then handed it off to a screenwriter.*

The particle in multi-word verbs may appear more or less logical on
 the surface.

While 'over' certainly invokes the 'across, transfer' action /
 process, 'off' is often used in a shedding, relinquishing, giving way,
 on both sides of the Atlantic (to take off a coat, a hands-off
 approach). So both particles seem reasonable choices, though the shift in focus is interesting.